# Why mapper throws ArrayIndexoutofboundexception?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to read a CSV file line by line and send the key value pair of those lines which contain "India" as substring. For this I have developed the below code.

Mapper Code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class MapperCode extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
        String Line=value.toString();
        String out="";
        String search_line=Line;
        String splitter[]=Line.split(" ");
        String searchStr="india";
        for(String words:splitter)
        {
            if(searchStr.equals(words))
            {
                 out=out+"\n"+search_line;
                 System.out.println(out);
            }
        }
        String keyvalpair[]=out.split(",");
        context.write(new Text(keyvalpair[2].trim()), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(keyvalpair[9].trim())));
    }
}
```

Dataset

```
Clarissa Chun,30,United States,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,0,1,1
Yogeshwar Dutt,29,India,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,0,1,1
Jaime Espinal,27,Puerto Rico,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,1,0,1
Johan Eurén,27,Sweden,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,0,1,1
Karam Gaber,32,Egypt,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,1,0,1
```

Exception

```
17/03/17 21:11:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :        attempt_201703140915_0030_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at MapperCode.map(MapperCode.java:26)
        at MapperCode.map(MapperCode.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

Please help me. Advance Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies here.

```
  String splitter[]=Line.split(" ");
```

You are trying to split using  'space'.In this perticular case you coulde use ','

```
String splitter[]=Line.split(",");
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you are trying to access to a index in an array which is not that size. Let me follow a small trace.

```
    1- Clarissa Chun,30,United States,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,0,1,1 
    2- splitter = ["Clarissa", "Chun,30,United", "States,2012,08-12-2012,Wrestling,0,0,1,1]
    3- keyvalpair = ["Clarissa"]
    4. keyvalpair[2] ==> ????
```

Did you get it? Hope this helps.

for that particular goal, try something much simpler, you will only need to do:

```
public class MapperCode extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        if(line.contains("india")) {
            String keyvalpair[] = line.split(",");
            context.write(new Text(keyvalpair[2].trim()), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(line)));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep i agree to you. When I tried with "," instead of " "(for splitting the line). It was the same exception again. @dbustosp